# Check actionscript 3 variable type?

Tags: actionscript-3

i have two objects   [object MovieClip] [object ContentDisplay]
i have to differentiate them abut i can't find a method in as3 check variable type, like in php have is_int...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`getQualifiedClassName(obj);` returns class name of given object

You can also check if object is for example a movieclip: `if (obj is MovieClip) {/* do something */}`

Comment: I believe `obj.constructor` will give you similar info too.

Comment: obj.className will also do it

Answer (score 3):

A similar strategy to `is_int()` would be to use the `is` keyword like this:

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();

trace(mc is MovieClip); // true
trace(mc is String); // false
```

Comment: this is second time you help me out! hehe ^_^